# При повторном вызове фрагмента получаю NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

Есть `MainActivity` в котором есть `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)` через который запускаются фрагменты, активность с настройками и диалог

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    if (id == R.id.nav_select_words) {
        ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fSelectWords);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_learn_words) {
        ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fLearnWords);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_repetition_words) {
        ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fRepetitionWords);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_see_all_words) {
        ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fSeeAllWords);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slide_all_words) {
        ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fSlideAllWords);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about_the_program) {
        AlertDialog dialog = DialogScreen.getDialog(this, DialogScreen.IDD_ABOUT);
        dialog.show();
    }

    ft.commit();
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Проблема заключается в следующем - при запуске приложения и последующим открытием фрагмента `nav_slide_all_words` через пункт меню. Фрагмент `nav_slide_all_words`открывается, слайды листаются. Если через меню зайти в другой фрагмент, а потом вернуться на этот то приложение вылетает с таким вот описанием:

```
12-28 09:43:35.727 25924-25924/** W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6321288)
12-28 09:43:35.727 25924-25924/** E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment(FragmentManager.java:667)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.restoreState(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:211)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onRestoreInstanceState(ViewPager.java:1319)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:11910)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2584)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2590)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:11888)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:468)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1094)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

код фрагмента `nav_slide_all_words`

```
public class FragmentSlideAllWords extends Fragment {
static final String TAG = "myLogs";
static final int PAGE_COUNT = 500;

ViewPager pager;
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

private SharedPreferences prefs;
boolean pref_key_check_animation;
final String PAGE_CURRENT = "page_current";

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slide_words, container, false);
    // меняем заголовок тулбара
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.nav_slide_all_words);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("");

    // подключаем преференсе
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    pref_key_check_animation = prefs.getBoolean("pref_key_check_animation", true);

    pager = (ViewPager) myView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_slide_words_pager);
    pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    int pageCurrent = prefs.getInt(PAGE_CURRENT, 0);
    pager.setCurrentItem(pageCurrent); // показываем с определенной страницы

    // отключаем или подключаем анимацию перехода
    if (pref_key_check_animation) {
        pager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
    }

    return myView;
}

private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    // Адаптер страниц также требует, чтобы вы реализовали getCount() метод, который возвращает количество страниц, которые адаптер будет создать
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    // метод для предоставления экземпляров FragmentSlideAllWords_ViewPager как новых страниц
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "public Fragment getItem(int position )" + position);
        return FragmentSlideAllWords_ViewPager.newInstance(position);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    // сохраняем номер текущей карточки
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
    ed.putInt(PAGE_CURRENT, pager.getCurrentItem());
    ed.commit();

    Log.d(TAG, "FragmentSlideAllWords onDetach()");
}
```

Comment: если вы про фрагмент то там всего 116 строк или я не правильно понял вопрос

Comment: @pavlofff, а зачем вам это? В стактрейсе нету ссылок на код автора вообще. Весь стактрейс относится к `Android API`

Comment: А ну да.. не надо. Не внимательно посмотрел :(

Answer (score 2):

Проблему решил с помощью этого поста: [пост](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596380/fragmentstatepageradapter-fails-to-load-the-fragments-again-when-i-get-back-to-o), нужно было в при вызове фрагмента дописать `.addToBackStack(null);` `ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fSlideAllWords).addToBackStack(null);`